# Accepting requests from authorized application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-authentication

My ASP.NET API currently accepts requests from authenticated and registered users. I want to add some new API methods that should only respond to requests coming from certain applications -- say a website I created.

How do I handle this "application authentication" scenario in my ASP.NET API app?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to go is to pass some secret key [`KEY`] in the requests header that your server will verify. To make it more secure and ensure that no man-in-the-middle can sniff your secret key the better approach is to pass token which is `sha(KEY:timestamp)` along with `timestamp` use in the sha function.

Once you receive such request on your API server you should verify that received timestamp is not too old/expired and construct serverToken=`sha(KEY:timestamp)`. If token from header is the same as serverToken then request is authenticated.